# Is there a way to access a client side object in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am just starting working with react and I am trying to use a web sdk. With client side code, the library is very easy to use: Add its script to the page header and, when the document is ready, it provides you with an object that has properties, methods and events. My goal would be to have access to that object methods and properties inside react. Is it even possible?
In the code below `AddScript` will create an object called `Stuff` on the client side and using the browser dev tools I can confirm that the object exists and it not null. How do I use Staff in React?

```
export class MyStuff extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      await  AddScript();

 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time with this question:

```
window.Staff
```

has the required object.